# What put options would the Universa Tail Fund have bought?

Tags: options, option-pricing, risk-management, hedging, option-strategies

According to this Bloomberg article, Universa was up 3,600% in March 2020, by hedging with extremely out-of-the-money puts: https://www.bloomberg.com/news/articles/2020-04-08/taleb-advised-universa-tail-risk-fund-returned-3-600-in-march

Near the end of the article, and according to a chart from the fund, it's described that *"a portfolio invested 96.7% in the S&P 500 and 3.3% in Universa’s fund would have been unscathed in March, a month in which the U.S. equity benchmark fell 12.4%."*

***What put options might they have bought?***

Comment: Yes: What options did they buy and *how many did they buy*. Would be good to know.

Comment: Most likely it was with credit default swaps similar to what  Weinstein did at Saba Capital Management (+3,000%).